# Debugging a OperationApplicationException insert failed

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, batch-processing, android-contentresolver

I am going to try to simplify this situation as much as possible.

Observe the following code:

```
//... 
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> batch = Lists.newArrayList();

while(recordsToProcess){
    //... Grabbing data
    //... built a ContentProviderOperation variable named operation

    batch.add(operation);

    //... setting recordsToProcess to true or false
}

try {
    mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(Contract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, batch);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem applying batch operation", e);
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem applying batch operation", e);
    }
}
```

During this process, an OperationApplicationException is thrown, which looks like:

```
... Problem applying batch operation
... android.content.OperationApplicationException: insert failed
... Stack Trace ....
```

I understand that this exception is "thrown if either the insert fails or if the number of rows affected didn't match the expected count" and/or "Thrown when an application of a ContentProviderOperation fails due the specified constraints."

My database schema has hardly any constraints and the data going in the operation is valid.

Is there any way to get more information to why the exception is thrown?  What constraint failed? etc...?

Comment: Does it work if you don't batch the inserts?

Comment: @CL, I'm sure he could debug by de-batching but it would be nice to have the logcat just tell you what insert it failed on.

Answer (score 3):

For debugging I would start with something like this

```
   {
   .........
        int i = 0;
        for (ContentProviderOperation op : ops) {
            applySingle(WorkoutProvider.AUTHORITY, op);
            Log.e(getTag(), Integer.toString(i));
            i++;
        }
    }


protected synchronized void applySingle(String authority, ContentProviderOperation op) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(op);
    try {
        App.getInstance().getContentResolver().applyBatch(authority, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(getTag(), "Error updating workout id to server's", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        Log.e(getTag(), "Error updating workout id to server's", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I would recommend debugging before that for loop and taking a look at what operation failed.